# Does the Uri function create a connection?

Tags: c#, uri

I use something like this in my C# program:

```
Uri myuri = new Uri(toCheck);
...
...
if (myuri.Contains("string here"))
{
...
}
```

Is the Uri function trying to connect to the remote server for getting the hostname?
I ask for performance reasons..

How would be the best way for determinating the hostname of an address like "http://website.com/news/page.php?id=1&news=5

thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, System.Uri is purely a string-handler, nothing there interacts with the network.

To get the HostName, use the [GetLeftPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.getleftpart.aspx) function and pass in the desired [UriPartial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x82988a2.aspx) value:

```
var uri = new Uri(@"http://website.com/news/page.php?id=1&news=5");
var hostname = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority); // http://website.com
```

Comment: I think .Host will return just 'website.com'

Answer (score 3):

No it wont connect.  Its just information about a uri.

To determine the hostname use the `.Host` property of the Uri object.

Comment: .Host is possibly indeed better than GetLeftPart in his scenario, that will just return website.com (just tested)

Comment: Yes that implementation using UriPartial.Authority also gets the scheme name with the host name.